# Match any domain complete url without quotes?

Tags: regex

So far I have the expression:

```
http://[^\.]*\.mydomain\.com/((.*?"))
```

Which matches...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/Images/favicon.ico"
```

But I really dont want that last little quotation mark in it. Could anyone tell me how I get rid of it?

Whats worse is that when I put this into GREP I get a message saying 'nested repeats' not allowed. Can anybody furnish me with a regex that will just match either

```
http://www.mydomain.com.anything/goes/here/
http://mydomain.com.anything/goes/here/
/mydomain.com.anything/goes/here
```

Im really struggling with this one.... :-(

Comment: you want to move the `"` outside the matching group or just remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using this to extract urls from HTML, and that you want to capture everything up to *but not including* the double quote. You can use a [non-capturing positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion for this:

```
http://[^\.]*\.mydomain\.com/.*?(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
http://[^\.]*\.mydomain\.com/(.*)
```